# Am I setting the DBCP pool size incorrectly?

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, executorservice, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using DBCP connection pooling with postgres and executor framework. I have a machine with 2 cores. Hence, I am setting the number of threads to 2.  I am I am setting initial size of the datasource to 2 and max active to 2 as well. However, the execution times are same as if I would have used a single connection and a single thread. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I am using an object (datasource) of type BasicDataSource (org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource) and then using methods datasource.setInitialSize(2) and dataSource.setMaxActive(2)

Comment: If possible, some code could help with the context. It's possible that your parallel algorithm is locking or blocked on some resource causing effectively serial operation.  It also depends how you're setting up the connection pool and how it's used. For a situation like this, it might be cleaner just to start up a connection per thread and run without the connection pool code.

Comment: I will post the code soon. If I create a connection separately each time the query object is created, it would cost me 60 ms that I would like to avoid. Hence, I wanted to use connection pooling. Also creating multiple connections would slow down the database and I might need to run thousands of queries. I will post the code soon

Comment: Well I said to manage the connection on the thread, not to destroy and recreate each time. If you use a worker/executor pattern and initialize a context on the thread, you won't need to recreate it each time saving this problem.